# display ldapsearch image result

Tags: javascript, html, ldap

I am trying to display the result of my ldap query into an html image.

I get the following result from ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -h server -p port -x -b "DC=dc,DC=domain,DC=com" -LLL "(mail=user@company.com)" -s "photo"
```

[image: result of ldap search query]

It returns an array of 5 elements.

I also verify it programmatically:
[image: Programmatically retrieving user photo]

I have tried to convert this result (which is supposed to be jpeg format) to base64:

```
let avatar = _.get(ldapUser, 'photo');
let avatar_b64 = new Buffer(avatar[0]).toString('base64');
```

And display it within an  tag:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,AAEAAADvv73vv73vv73vv70BAAAAAAAAAAwCAAAA...."
```

but it never shows anything...

Do you know what I am missing?

Comment: Data from 'photo' are already base64 encoded. What happens if you don't encode it ?

Comment: I did but it also doesn't work.